# Why is enqueueAction not getting executed the second time?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

I am currently writing a lightning component and came across this,

ComponentController.js

```
someFunction: function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.apexFunction");
    action.setParams({
        // Params
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
       console.log(response);
       // Response handling
    });
    action.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

apexClass.apxc

```
public class apexClass {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String apexFunction(String params) {
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(apiUrl);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        String payLoad = 'payload';
        req.setBody(payLoad);
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        return res.getBody();
    }
}
```

So when the function is called the first time the response is printed out but the next time the function is called, the response is not printed out(the function gets called though.

Comment: FYI, [one cause of a callback not happening](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209421/why-is-an-action-callback-not-getting-called).

Comment: can you post your calling code?

Comment: Where were you run the code? On LEXPage or a Standalone app?

Comment: @KeithC atleast the post request should execute, right? I mean while debugging I don't see any post request being executed in the networks tab in chrome console

Comment: @AntoJoy I'm not sure; the post may not be done immediately because the framework tries to group multiple requests into one request.

Answer (score 1):

Your Apex class method  does not have **AuraEnabled** annotation.

It is needed for lightning.

```
public class apexClass {
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static String apexFunction(String params) {
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(apiUrl);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        String payLoad = 'payload';
        req.setBody(payLoad);
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        return res.getBody();
    }
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex.htm

Comment: Oops sorry it has I just missed it out while copy pasting

Comment: Can you check debug logs to see is aura method is even called? is it the real code or pseudo code

Comment: First time it is being called ... a log is generated and also i can see the request was successful from the Networks tab in chrome. The second time and onwards, the function is invoked no logs are generated and neither is a post request (no request in the networks tab). Its a pseudo code

Comment: Was that component dynamically created? Is that component inside aura:if section? When you call the method 1st time , after parsing the response are you doing any change to the same or other component?

Comment: the component is not dynamically created. I havent used any aura:if section. I am only appending another div to the component on getting the response